# Issue with applying search filter in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I have a search option on the action bar and to the left side of it, I will have "**Search by University**". Similar to the amazon app in the screenshot.

[image]

So, when a user clicks on "Search by University", it takes them to a new activity to select any university from the list of universities acronyms that will be displayed.

**Now, my problem is because of space constraints on Mobile devices, I am using acronyms instead of full name of universities. I need a way to show mobile users full form of each acronym when they want to see. What is the best presentable way for providing that in mobile apps?** I was thinking of adding a Dialog for each acronym using an exclamatory icon or something? Not really sure.

Comment: `Multiline textView`

Comment: that will make the list look longer?

Comment: You can give Marquee effect on your textview. Check this easy tutorial: http://rajeshandroiddeveloper.blogspot.com.tr/2013/06/marquee-effect-in-textview-tutorial.html